# deactivate and shrink LV /tmp

Tags: lvm

How can I deactivate and shrink the Logical volume mounted as /tmp safely ?

```
lvm> lvreduce --size 30GB /dev/vg_server4/LogVolTmp
WARNING: Reducing active and open logical volume to 30.00 GiB
THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to reduce LogVolTmp? [y/n]:
```

thanks

Comment: unmount it and resize the filesystem first?

Comment: @TomYan how can I unmount /tmp when OS is running ?

Comment: I think it really depends on whether you have anything strictly requires `/tmp` running. Also some filesystem (e.g. btrfs)  supports online shrinking, so unmount *may not* be necessary either. Is it a system you cannot afford downtime or so?

Comment: @TomYan no ... downtime under 2h is no problem.
I have cPanel (apache, mysql, pureftpd) running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned, you will most likely need to umount the FS.

When unmounting the FS, you will likely want to switch to singleuser mode to safely unmount the /tmp. (Run `telinit 1`, `/sbin/init 1` or `systemctl isolate runlevel1.target` depending on distro age/brand.)

When resizing adding `-r` (`--resizefs`) switch to [lvreduce/lvextend/lvresize](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvresize) will take care of resizing the FS and LV in the right order. Caveat: it does not handle LUKS encrypted volumes yet.